# Warning: "Parethesize the multiplication of 'D' and its transpose to ensure the result is Hermetian."

Tags: matlab, matrix, warnings, multiplication, parentheses

[image]

As you see in the screen shot above, I have the following expression in my Matlab m-file code:
`K = P * D * D' * P;`
Where, P is an nxn matrix, and D is a nx1 column vector (n=4, if it matters).

Why am I getting this warning message?
What changes if I use or don't use parenthesis there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Floating-point arithmetic is not associative.  So in general, `a * (b * c)` won't necessarily give the same result as `(a * b) * c`.

Your statement as written is equivalent to `((P * D) * D') * P`, so the compiler is warning you that if you're relying on the Hermitian symmetry of `D * D'`, you should force it to calculate exactly that.

Comment: Also note that in general, a * (b * c) can have different complexity to compute compared to (a * b) * c depending on the dimensions of the matrices. Last: matlab is very efficient on computing (A'* A)

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth so which is right: `((P * D) * D') * P` or `P *( D * D') * P` for the question?

Comment: @kww - Depends what the OP wants to do.

Comment: There's a small benchmark and some additional helpful comments here: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/312224

Answer (score 2):

As a side note: you can always do

```
K = (K + K') / 2;
```

To enforce the Hermetian-ity of `K`, but it's better to compute it as Hermitian in the first place as is suggested by the `P * (D * D') * P` hint.

Edit: Actually, one thing to note is that `K` is only going to be necessarily Hermitian if `P` is diagonal in general.  Even with `P` as a permutation matrix (as the letter implies), there's not guarantee of `K` being Hermitian.  The only guaranteed Hermitian part `D * D'`.