# Matlab: Computing norm of a vector

Tags: matlab

`a` is a n by 1 vector. `X` is a n by n matrix.
I want to computer a norm of a vector `X*a`. I know I can do it by `norm(X*a)`. By strangeness arises when I want to do it myself:

If I do it `sqrt(a'*X'*X*a)`
I got the warning of 
`Parethesize the multiplication of 'X' and its transpose to ensure the result is Hermetian.”`

Therefore should the norm be `sqrt(a'*(X'*X)*a)` (as the warning suggest) or

`sqrt((a'*X')*(X*a))` (which seems more correct to me).

I try to compare them together with the `norm` function for some simple examples but they seem to be the same. But if I apply it to my program which involve time-dependent matrix they are different (shown in plotting).

Comment: The m-lint warning is [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724549/warning-parethesize-the-multiplication-of-d-and-its-transpose-to-ensure-the).  As for why your time-dependent matrix gives a different result, we can't possibly help with that without an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); please provide a short piece of code that will replicate your problem.

Comment: @TroyHaskin which of `sqrt(a'*(X'*X)*a)` or `sqrt((a'*X')*(X*a))` should I use? They have different precedence.

Comment: I'd say that ensuring `X'*X` is Hermitian is only really important if you're looking at `a`'s conjugacy to the product, which you're not.  I think the best, non-`norm` way is `v=X*a; vnorm=sqrt(v'*v);`  No muss; no fuss.

Comment: As a C programmer, I prefer to do it like this: `v = X*a; vnorm=sqrt(sum(v.^2));`  About getting different results... make sure that `X` and `a` are of class `double`. You can use: `v = double(X)*double(a);`. Make sure all elements are real (no imaginary part). Consider: floating point computation is not 100% accurate, but using double precision tend to be accurate enough.